Call openai.Audio.transcribe('model_name', bytes, prompt=language_prompt, response_format='verbose_json') with timeout
Is it possible to call the OpenAI speech to text API in Python with a timeout so if it doesn't respond within the timeout the call is cancelled? The call has the following signature:
openai.Audio.transcribe('model_name', bytes, prompt=language_prompt,
response_format='verbose_json')
I tried using the Python requests library but it didn't work. Can I possible use the Python OpenAI module for this purpose? Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Did you try some test examples that contain python snippets? https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/speech-to-text/quickstart

are you using async or sync & why do you want to cancel? E.g. for cost reason or to free up some memory or...
E.g. for a streaming response you could potentially close() the connection:
https://community.openai.com/t/cancel-the-openai-api-request-without-deducting-the-cost-from-the-balance/719556

I'm currently using sync and I want to cancel the call if the latency reaches a certain threshold. I'm not using streaming at the moment.

Can I use the Python requests library to make this call?

I solved this problem by using the Python requests library.
